# The 5min timeout should be reset after each re-edit

Tags: discussion, edits, grace-period

So I often edit a post, and find I made a mistake 4min later, and frantically try edit quickly, and publish, and realize that I didn't put the proper tag, and publish, and then I see human verification nightmare, and then quickly enter the often-hard-to-read alnums, therefore slowing me down, and then post, and damn! I missed it... "last edited 1s ago".

One often doesn't want to display a trail of mistakes, and worse still, risk the post going to the irreversible CW state. So, can you reset the 5min timeout on each re-edit?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe of a `[feture-request]` that was rejected because, if this was enabled, *somebody* on Meta would keep the grace period open for two days by continuously editing his post every five minute

Comment: Everybody makes mistakes and you can't turn post CW with 2 or 3 edits. [Don't worry. Be happy. Don't worry. Be happy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Don't_Worry,_Be_Happy.ogg)

Answer (score 1):

A reset after each re-edit could lead to problems.    However if there is less then 3 min of the timeout left after **1st** edit it maybe worth increaseing the remaining timeout to 3 min.

Comment: Why would a reset lead to problems?